# Keep values and communicate them while changing of fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, checkbox

I have 2 fragments linked with a bottom navigation view.

- On fragment 1, there is a checkbox
- On fragment 2, there is a spinner

I want that when I change a fragment, if the checkbox is unchecked, the spinner is disabled. Moreover, when I come back to the 1st fragment, the checkbox state is kept and the spinner selected item o the second fragment too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to send data between each fragment using a bundle `setArguments()`. The down side is that these values are only available as the app runs. If you want the state of your app to be more persistent, then you can store the state of your app permanently on disk with either `SharedPreferences` or a database. Each fragment will read and write data when necessary. See [Storage Options](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) in the Android documentation for more details.

Comment: I tried with Shared Preferences, but it didn't work. I saved when I called onPause(). Is that the right event?

Comment: @Tim241 You should post a new question showing what you tried. First be sure to read [ask] and [mcve] for tips on asking a good question that will attract the answer you are looking for.

Comment: In fact, sharedPreferences didn't work because I forgot to commit... Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

before moving to fragment 2. find the reference of fragment1 using findfragmentbyid() from mainactivity and check the checkbox status and send the appropriate argument data to fragment2 and get that argument data in fragment2 to disable or enable spinner.At the end, you need to perform communication between fragments. read this official article. its worth it.
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: This can also be done by keeping references to each fragment as fields in the class. This means you do not need to find the fragment each time.

Comment: i agree with you